# Public method from Model not visible on Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have method on my Model:

```
    public string GetSubscriptionCode()
    {
        return String.Format(Name.ToLower().Replace("", "-"));
    }
```

Than when I want to call that method on the view i am getting an error that there is no such method in my model:

```
 <div id="@Model.GetSubscriptionCode()"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Update:
Ooops, I mixed up my models, I put my method in to wrong one...
Now i would remove this question if i could

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your view is strongly typed to a model:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

where `MyViewModel` contains this public method:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetSubscriptionCode()
    {
        return String.Format(Name.ToLower().Replace("", "-"));
    }
}
```

you should be able to perfectly fine access it in the view:

```
<div id="@Model.GetSubscriptionCode()"></div>
```

Don't worry if Visual Studio underlines it saying that it doesn't exist. Intellisense in views is far from perfect. Simply run your application and it will work as expected.

Comment: All working, i just mixed up my models...Anyway i can remove this question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an extension method so you need to include/import the namespace implementing that extension method.